# why is my ruby string becoming an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

Here is the code and the output, where inbound_text is a string as you can see:

```
 puts inbound_text  
 data = {:input => "#{inbound_text}", 'user_key' => ENV['USER_KEY'], 'client_name' => "#{bot_client_name}" }
 puts data
```

The output:

```
changed sms_text to inbound_text
{'input' =>"[\"changed sms_text to inbound_text\"]", "user_key"=>"3b9ccb48e734fce6b982a9c1c2cef301", "client_name"=>"14155086888"}
```

I cannot figure out why :input keeps getting an array.  client_name is also a string, as you can see, but doesn't seem to have a similar problem.

Comment: It's not an array, it's a string, you probably gave the inbound_text an array and with #{} it converted that array to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
inbound_text = inbound_text.first
```

before initializing the data hash.

You probably have inbound_text set to an actual array and you thought that a single-element array like

```
inbound_text = ["changed sms_text to inbound_text"]
```

is going to give you the text inside the array. That's not the case:

```
["changed sms_text to inbound_text"].to_s #=> "[\"changed sms_text to inbound_text\"]"
```

So you probably just want to get the first (and only element) in the array and then do the calculations.

Comment: close --- the payload that I received looked like a string with puts, but with .inspect was, in fact, an array like you said, and so [0] or probably .to_s would get it.